# What is wrong with my regex pattern?

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to match all names that have **First Name**, then **2 or more spaces**, and **Last Name**. This should be trivial, yet I am having trouble.

Suppose my table, `KCChiefs`, is populated as such:

```
player
---------------
Matt  Cassel
Jamaal  Charles
Thomas Jones
Dwayne Bowe  
Tony  Moeaki
88 TonyG
TylerTh1gpen
```

**Note**: Cassel, Charles, and Moeaki have 2 spaces separating their first and last name.

Currently, my regular expression in my SQL statement is as follows:

`SELECT * FROM KCChiefs WHERE player REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+[:space:]{2,}[A-Za-z]+$'`

As I understand it, my pattern is matching

- one or more characters that are A-Z or a-z
- followed by 2 or more white spaces
- followed by one or more characters that are A-Z or a-z

However, I end up with an *empty result set*. Can an extra pair of eyes help me see what I don't see (or misunderstanding)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM KCChiefs WHERE player REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+[[:space:]]{2,}[A-Za-z]+$'
```

Otherwise `[:space:]` will be interpreted as "one character out of `:`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `c` or `e`".

Comment: I am forever indebted to you, my friend.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you have the proper regex in mind, but improper syntax. Try it using `^[a-Za-z]+[[:space:]]{2,}[A-Za-z]+$`.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 3):

I believe your character class is incorrect. Try `[[:space:]]`